# 'X_train' is not defined と表示されてしまいます。どのようにすれば良いでしょうか。

Tags: python

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import numpy as np

clf=RandomForestClassifier()
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)

importances=clf.feature_importances_
std= np.std([tree.feature_importances_ for tree in clf.estimators_],axis=0)
indices= np.argsort(importances)[::-1]

plt.figure()
plt.title("Feature importances")
plt.bar(np.array(X_train.columns)[indices],color="r",yerr=std[indices],align="center")
plt.xticks(np.array(X_train.columns)[indices],ratation=45, ha="right")
plt.xlim([-1,X.shape[1]])
plt.show()
```

Comment: 表示された通り、提示されたソースコードの中では`X_train`(と`y_train`も)が定義・設定されていません。例えばJupyter-Notebook/Lab等でそれ以前のセルにて用意しておく必要が有ったりするのでは？ 参考にしている書籍やWeb記事があればそれを良く読んでそれと同様に作業を行ってみてください。例えば類似の変数名やオブジェクト名を取り扱っているこんな記事が検索で見つかります。[【AIプログラミング】いろいろな分類器でDigitを分類、ランダムフォレストで分類](https://panda-clip.com/digit-randomforest/), [最新アンサンブル学習SklearnStackingの性能調査(LBGM, RGF, ET, RF, LR, KNNモデル](https://zenn.dev/r2en/articles/797abfc4de68505b3b49)

Comment: @kunif さん、コメントで回答することは避け、なるべく「回答」として投稿するようにお願いいたします。質問へのコメントは質問に足りない情報を求めたり質問を改善するための提案をしたりする場所になります。サイト初心者の方にとっては、対応の仕方に戸惑ってしまうのではないかと思います。

Comment: 少し文字数は多いですが、回答では無くヒントを提示しているつもりです。この程度では解決に結びつかず、質問者さんの更なる調査や作業が必要になるでしょう。